# how to append items in list in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

could you please tell me how to append items in list in angular  ?I am using xslt transformation first then I want to add item in list on button click [here](http://xsltransform.net/pNmBy1y) is my code

On button click I just want to add `"Test"` item in list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="list">
        <hmtl ng-app="app">
            <head>
                <title>New Version!</title>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
                <script>
                    angular.module('app',[]).controller('cntr',function($scope){

                    $scope.name="dd";
                    $scope.append =function(){

                    alert('append');

                    }

                    });
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div ng-controller="cntr">
                    {{4+6}}
                    <ul>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
                    </ul>
                    <button ng-click="append()">Append</button>
                </div>


            </body>

        </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**data.xml**

```
<list>
    <name>A new XSLT engine is added: Saxon 9.5 EE, with a namecense (thank you Michael Kay!)</name>
    <name>XSLT 3.0 support when using the new Saxon 9.5 EE engine!</name>
    <name>Preview your result as HTML when doctype is set to HTML (see this example)</name>
    <name>Preview your result as PDF when doctype is set to XML and your document starts with root element of XSL-FO. Apache FOP is used to generate the PDF</name>
    <name>Added some namenks to useful XSLT sites</name>
</list>
```

any update

Comment: Please remove tag `angular` and it directs to Angular 2/4. Your question is related to AngularJs so `angularjs` tag is sufficiant for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more an angularjs question, rather than XSLT, because before you can write XSLT you need to know what you are transforming to, and it sounds like you don't know at the moment.

By "append items in list" I am assuming you mean you want to add a new name that appears in the unordered list in html. To do this in angularjs, you should really be storing the names in an array property in the model, and using the "ng-repeat" direct to render the li, rather than pre-rendering the list with XSLT.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="list">
        <hmtl ng-app="app">
            <head>
                <title>New Version!</title>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
                <script>
                    angular.module('app',[]).controller('cntr',function($scope){

                    $scope.names = [
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
                    ];

                    $scope.name="dd";
                    $scope.append = function(){
                        $scope.names.push($scope.name);
                    }
                    });
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div ng-controller="cntr">
                    {{4+6}}
                    <ul>
                       <li ng-repeat="name in names track by $index">
                           {{name}}
                       </li> 
                    </ul>
                    <button ng-click="append()">Append</button>
                </div>
            </body>
        </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

EDIT: In answer to your comment, if you want the existing items in the XML pre-rendered, even before angular kicks in, try this instead...

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="list">
        <hmtl ng-app="app">
            <head>
                <title>New Version!</title>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
                <script>
                    angular.module('app',[]).controller('cntr',function($scope){

                    $scope.names = [];

                    $scope.name="dd";
                    $scope.append = function(){
                        $scope.names.push($scope.name);
                    }
                    });
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div ng-controller="cntr">
                    {{4+6}}
                    <ul>
                       <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
                       <li ng-repeat="name in names track by $index">
                           {{name}}
                       </li> 
                    </ul>
                    <button ng-click="append()">Append</button>
                </div>
            </body>
        </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: your answer is correct but there is issue in that .example if I  have server side rendering other words we are doing xslt transformation on server ,.if we are doing`cntrl +u` we see the parsing data ..but after your solution I am able to append data ..but I see {{}} while usng `cntrl +u` no server side rending

Comment: could you please suggest better way

Comment: Server side rendering should not make a difference as the html + js that is rendered still gets executed on the client, so it shouldn't matter where it is generated. I have spotted a mistake in my XSLT which I have corrected though, to allow multiple items to be appended.

Comment: Also, when using angular, which will manipulate the DOM, you should avoid using CTRL + U to view the source. Instead, do CTRL + SHIFT + I to inspect the code, as this will show you the HTML after angular has udpated it.

Comment: `how google knows what will be present in my page`..ok it is rendering issue I will try to resolve..I am saying `using your solution it create SEO isue`